# European citizen taking residence in two EU countries and seeking citizenship from both

Tags: residency, dual-citizenship

If for example a Spanish citizen happens to find two houses in two close cities that are close to each other (for example a French city and a Belgian city), applies for residency in both of them and manages somehow to afford rent costs and meet the work requirements in both countries  (let's say for example he resides with him family in one country and pays rent on his own in the other one, and works part time in Belgium and part time in France, for a needed extension of time), and likewise also assuming that he manages not to let know each country's authorities about his own status in the other country (for example opening a bank account in a country exclusively with its own issued document, in order to avoid double taxation and using exclusively each document for its own territory), can he for example seek citizenship from both countries after 5 years (Belgium and France require 5 years for their citizenships)? Would it be legal to seek both citizenships in that case? In case this is illegal, how would he eventually be caught?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is asking for advice on the best way to avoid committing a fraudulent application for citizenship in 2 countries at the same time. It ignores the fact that nationalization is **not** soley based on residence.

Comment: I did write about meeting work requirements as well. Check that

Comment: And by the way language knowledge, work requirements and whatnot were already assumed by default.

Comment: @us er Would the part time earnings in each location be sufficient to meet all the costs associated with that location? If not, how would you explain the discrepancy if asked to do so? Would you plan to seek citizenship from both locations at exactly the same time? How would you answer any questions about other citizenships? In applying for residency in the two cities, what trail would there be linking those applications back to you as a Spanish citizen? How would you deal with eg future passport applications that might ask about other citizenships? You’d be weaving a complicated web of lies

Comment: My question was purely hypothetical, I don't even live in France nor in Belgium

Comment: Your hypothetical question lacks research. There are double taxation treaties to avoid the double taxation situation. Fraud is therefore not needed. Being a person of [Good character](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/good-character-nationality-policy-guidance) is often a precondition for nationalization for most countries. Fraud would probably lead to refusal and possibly the nationalization would be nullified if found out later.

Comment: Purely hypothetical questions are off-topic. See the [help] files.

Comment: @MarkJohnson the question is asking whether it is legal.  If you think it's fraudulent, then you should post an answer saying "no" rather than vote to close the question.

Comment: @phoog That's my decision to make, **not yours**. Asking for advice how to avoid getting caught commiting a fraud is a perfectly valid reason to close a question.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I don't see any evidence of fraud in the question.

Comment: @phoog Thank you for clarifying to Mark Johnson, which every single time he has to moan and complain about my every single question

Comment: @phoog But I do, since part of the definition of [§ 263 - Fraud StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_stgb/englisch_stgb.html#p2372) is :'(1)... **or** maintaining an error under false pretences or distorting or suppressing true facts...(2) The attempt is punishable.' and part of the OP question is: `and likewise also assuming that he manages not to let know each country's authorities about his own status in the other country`.

Comment: Because probably I didn't know that one has to declare his own status in an other country, since it regards that other country only? And I asked whether it is LEGAL in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention France, the residence requirement for naturalisation has been interpreted as having the [“center of your life”](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F2213) in France. For example, if you live in France and your spouse and children live abroad, naturalisation can be denied. It's deliberately not about meeting formal criteria (like spending a predefined number of days in France) but by definition excludes living a life split between two countries and gives the authorities and justice system complete flexibility to deal with such cases.

In practice, what happens during a naturalisation procedure is that you will at least have an interview with the police (probably an officer of the [General Directorate for Internal Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Directorate_for_Internal_Security)) and the mayor of the town where you live will be asked for an opinion (in a small town, s/he might know you or inquire in person, in large city, they would typically mandate a social worker to pay a visit to your address). It's not a deep investigation but it might still be difficult to hide the fact you have a kind of double life to them.

Another way this could come back to haunt you is that if you run into some serious problem with the law (or even, possibly, with a private citizen who has reasons to report you to the authorities) at a later point. It's entirely possible for the original decision to be invalidated as fraudulent. At this point, any action you took to dissimulate your true situation (like failing to report income or opening two bank accounts) only make matters worse as they establish fraudulent intent.

Comment: Ok, but how would they realise when such an individual exits France, if Belgium and France have basically no border checks and hence no date stamps?

Comment: And how would they realise if this individual has opened also a bank account in the other country, if he uses only each ID in its own issuing country? If this person uses a Belgian ID with Belgian address to open a bank account in Belgium and likewise for the French counterpart with its relative same features, how can they eventually cross check data? Obviously I'm not intending to do that, but I just wonder how they would catch such an individual, if he manages not to get any interception in terms of information

Comment: @user That's exactly what the second paragraph is about. [This other answer of mine](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158295/how-do-schengen-countries-know-if-someone-has-overstayed-internally/158319#158319) also seems relevant. As I explained (and unlike some other countries), France doesn't have any hard threshold for trips abroad.

Comment: Ok, regarding staying authorities cannot do that much, but what about the bank accounts opened with two different IDs (Belgium and France allow EU citizens to request a card specific for them) used each one for its own issuing place? Either they have a big bank accounts/fiscal registry including multiple countries' citizens or they exchange data between countries, even though I don't know on which criteria they do so is they have nothing to be assuming over

Comment: @user And that's what the third paragraph is about. Just to give one example, one way it could be discovered is by a police search finding some paper from your other bank. Of course until you attract that kind of attention, you might very well be able to hide it.

Comment: @user Why do you think you even need two IDs? The focus on automated enforcement or big data exchange is entirely misplaced. You do have to prove your links with France, for example income and work over several years. That's where most people fail and would be incredibly difficult to maintain in two countries. Why even expand ressources trying to fight this very theoretical issue?

Comment: I was just remotely told that some people living in that area managed to do so, so that's why I asked and hence got curious about that. Some managed to do that with France and Belgium and some did that with Germany and France.

Comment: And since I've heard vaguely that someone managed to get two citizenships with a small time span between them (application processing times and other stuff) this very thing triggered my curiosity about how the EU allows this kind of stuff to be got away with.

Comment: Seemingly the only thing needed to circumvent any catching for double life and its whole web is to be careful on not intersecting/commoning anything between the two countries, that's it. But I might be wrong.

Comment: @user What do you know about these people's situation? A scenario like the one you describe requires considerable effort and years of preparation. It seems more likely to me that they would qualify for one of these citizenships through another route than naturalisation (things like marriage, ancestry, investment, etc.) These often have lighter requirements, sometimes residence isn't even required at all. The EU has absolutely no role in citizenship issues.

Comment: I just heard people saying stuff about other people whom I don't know (I've never been in North Europe), people knowing people knowing people and so on...that I do not know. They just happened to be placed in the midst of two countries and that's it. I don't know plenty of details.

Comment: Citizenship requirements are a national issue, but also it's considerable that citizenship is not any country's, other than its own, business

Comment: I mean this thing would not happen in US and Canada, nor would have happened for a pair of countries like France and UK when the latter was part of the EU since it was not even in Schengen (and hence entry/exit records where available in that case, and now more so because it's no longer in the EU)

Comment: @user There are many scenarios where you don't get stamps (all EU citizens, their family, mistakes and laziness) and to my knowledge no systematic record of entries and exits that would be queried for naturalisation applications. Like I said, the focus on this is entirely misplaced, simply having a job in both countries and being able to submit pay slips and a reasonable income is a much higher hurdle.

Comment: The scenarios you imagined are very contrived. Since you don't actually know any specifics, it's much more likely that the people in question, if they exist at all, got one or both citizenships though another route. It's entirely possible for someone living in the UK to get both British citizenship through naturalisation and French citizenship by marrying a French citizen (it's called *déclaration* in French).

Comment: Well the employer pays taxes for the worker, the only thing that the worker needs to do is to log into the country's social security website, and download all his contribution record paid by his employer through taxes, that's the proof that could be submitted.

Comment: What do you mean? What do taxes have to do with it? You need to find the time and energy to maintain two jobs that pay enough to make your bank account look good.

Comment: Edited my comment

Comment: @user Sorry to be blunt but you're living in fantasy land. There is no "social security website" where you could download this stuff in France. Again, the process is not based on database lookups. It's your problem to keep paper pay slips and submit them with your application, you have to prove residence and ties to France. The focus on border checks or what data could be crossed-reference to detect some unlikely fraud is *entirely misplaced*, this is not at all how this works.

Comment: I thought it existed in every country, here in Italy we have it and after logging in one can really see all his "côtisations" that he has paid thorough his entire working career (or whatever the employer paid for him). I don't know the whole details about each country (I did ask the question in the first place), but regardless of each proceedings to entertain about single steps, I did hear that people living there managed to get two citizenships together basically because of their location, and ended up having 3 EU citizenships at the end,  and I don't know whether it's a lie.

Comment: So they ended up having their initial EU citizenship plus these two, and I don't know whether what it's been said is true.

Comment: @user I already touched upon this yesterday, it's entirely possible to get two or three EU citizenships but what's your basis to claim it's “because of the location”? Being close to the border doesn't help at all, you need to reside *in* the country. And maintaining two separate homes, holding two separate jobs over several years takes a lot of effort. It's much more likely that one of the citizenship was obtained through investment or marriage for example.

Comment: I did not write that they lived in one country only in a city near the border, I did write that I heard that they managed somehow to rent a studio, home or whatever fitted them, gain residency over that in the other country. It could be that they resided with their family in one country (hence not paying rent, or paying little of it) whilst they paid the other one in full, so even the costs are not that big when co-living in one country

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119709/discussion-between-us-er-and-relaxed).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119719/discussion-on-answer-by-relaxed-european-citizen-taking-residence-in-two-eu-coun).